# intent.putExtra() and intent.getStringExtra() are not working. getStringExtra returns null

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

`intent.putExtra()` and `intent.getStringExtra()` are not working. getStringExtra returns null

At sending side:

```
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChooseUserActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

             intent.putExtra("Name",imageName);
```

At receiving side:

```
            Intent secondIntent = getIntent();
            String nameImage = "Something " + secondIntent.getStringExtra("Name");
            Log.i("Name of the Image: ",nameImage);
```

The output of the Log cat:

[image]

Comment: it'd be nice if you write your log than uploading its image. @Apoorv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first put Extras in Intent and then start activity not after it

```
//create intent
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChooseUserActivity.class);

//put extras
intent.putExtra("Name",imageName);

//start activity
startActivity(intent);
```